# Ad Viewability Inside Third-Party iFrames

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, ads, advertisement-server

So with Google recent acquisition of spider.io, everyone is talking about ad viewability.

Aside from spider.io's patented technique and comScore's patented geometric technique... is there any other way of detecting ad viewability using javascript inside a 3rd-party iframe?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd really like to know how spider.io can get past what the reset of us haven't. I have a suspicioin that there is some security hole they are exploiting some of us aren't aware of.

Answer (score 1):

There are to way to detect cross domain view-ability

1)  request animation frame (IOS).
2) IntersectionObserver  (API chrome, firefox etc).

Both example is here.

```
var options = {
threshold: [0.0, 0.3, 0.7, 1.0]
```

};

```
var element = document.getElementById("element");

function intersectionObserver(callback)
{

    function callbackObserver(entries, observer)
    {
        entries.forEach(function(entry)
        {
            callback.call(this, entry.intersectionRatio == 0)
        });
    }
    var observer = new IntersectionObserver(callbackObserver, options);
    observer.observe(element);
}


function reqAnimFrame(callback)
{
    var lastCalled;
    var fps;
    var timediff;

    function requestAnimFrame()
    {
        if (!lastCalled)
        {
            lastCalled = Date.now();
            fps = 0;
        }
        timediff = (Date.now() - lastCalled);

        if (timediff <= 1000)
        {
            fps++;
        }
        else
        {
            lastCalled = Date.now();
            fps = 0;
        }
        callback.call(this, fps <= 10);
        window.requestAnimationFrame(requestAnimFrame);
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(requestAnimFrame);
}
var callback = function(isNotView)
{
    console.log(isNotView);
}

//IOS
reqAnimFrame(callback);

//Other then IOS
intersectionObserver(callback);
```